# Linux "strings" command with -el option to a binary file and how to replace the result strings

Tags: string, replace, binary, endianness

I wanted to replace certain strings within a binary file, namely file.bin, below are my problem:

- I have a binary file
- I can look for string "abc" within file.bin using a Linux command line ***strings file.bin|grep abc***
- I can replace the string "abc" to "xyz" using ***sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g file.bin***
- All the strings "abc" have been replaced.
- However, i then look for string "abc" using strings command with -el option (which mean encoding 16-bit little endian): ***strings -el file.bin|grep abc***
- I still find a lot of string "abc"
- How can i replace this string "abc" to "xyz"? I want all "abc" strings replaced with string "xyz" in the result of ***strings -el***

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you save sed's output in a new file and check that one? Or are you doing an in-place edit and forgot to include the needed command line option when making your post?

Comment: I did an in-place edit & forgot to put -i during the post, anyway it’s not the sed command that we should worry, however how the strings command print the 16 bit little endian & how we replace these strings